# Laravel order user by role

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have table users and pivot table role_user, not every user has a role. I need to make a query and get all users, and order them by roles, which join statement should I use then, how would that query look like then?
I need some similar query to this, but so that users with that have roles come first and not the ones that don't have roles like now:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
                     ->leftJoin('role_user', 'users.id', '=', 'role_user.user_id')
                     ->orderBy('role_id')
                     ->get();
```

Comment: Maybe you should give us some more information about what you want to achieve. For example show us how your tables look like and by what you want to order your results.

Comment: Well, user table has some fields with info about the user, and then I have pivot table role_user where I store role and user id for users that have some roles, in my query I would like to get all users, with or without roles and have them sort by roles, so that users with roles are first and the users without roles come later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code should do the trick:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
  ->leftJoin('role_user', 'users.id', '=', 'role_user.user_id')
  ->orderBy(\DB::raw('role_id IS NULL'))
  ->orderBy('role_id')
  ->get();
```

This way you'll first sort by **role_id IS NULL**, that will be **0** if user has **role_id** set and **1** if user has no role, so users with role set will go first. Then within each group users will be ordered by **role_id**.

Comment: This is almost the solution, is there a way, I could get this kind of result but have instead of users listed from the roles with greatest role_id first, users with smallest role_id first?