# Laravel - order by number of entries

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

This is a follow up from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37542924/laravel-order-user-by-role). I have a  query that looks like this:

```
$users = User::leftjoin('role_user', 'users.id', '=', 'role_user.user_id')
              ->select('users.*')
              ->orderBy(DB::raw('role_id IS NULL'))
              ->groupBy('users.id')
              ->orderBy('role_id', 'asc')
              ->get();
```

When I do it like that I get distinct values for users, and they are ordered by role_id in asc order, the only thing with this query is that users that have two or more roles are behind the ones with who have only one role. For example, user has roles with `id=1` and `id=2`, and other user has a only a role with `id=1`, that user will be before the user with two roles in the list. I would like to change that and have users with more roles above the ones with only one role.

Comment: you can use group_by for avoid duplicate

Comment: Can you try the group by on the "role"

Comment: Can you display the structure of the table

Comment: @ImtiazPabel I have updated question with your suggestion, but that is still not what I need

Comment: @YagnikDetroja group_by role would just group them by role, which is not what I need, and table structure is simple, I have users with some info fields about them and a pivot table where I have id, role_id and user_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following query worked for me in the end:

```
User::leftjoin('role_user', 'users.id', '=', 'role_user.user_id')
                               ->select('users.*')
                               ->selectRaw('user_id, count(*) as count')
                               ->orderBy(DB::raw('role_id IS NULL'))
                               ->groupBy('users.id')
                               ->orderBy('count', 'DESC')
                               ->orderBy('role_id', 'asc')
                               ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use [Query Scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#query-scopes) and [Querying Relations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations)

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    ...

    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Role', 'role_user');
    }

    // Scope users who have a specified role
    public function scopeHasRole($query, $role) {
        return $query->whereHas('roles', function ($q) use ($role) {
            $q->where('id', $role);
        });
    }

    // Scope users who have a set of roles
    public function scopeHasRoles($query, $roles) {
        if (! is_array($roles)) {
            return $this->scopeHasRole($query, $roles);
        }

        return $query->whereHas('roles', function ($q) use ($roles) {
            $q->whereIn('id', $roles);
        });
    }

    // Scope a user who don't have any roles.
    public function scopeDoesntHaveAnyRoles($query) {
        return $query->whereDoesntHave('roles');
    }

}
```

Example usage:

```
User::doesntHaveAnyRoles(); // return users don't have any roles.

User::hasRole(1)->orderBy('id', 'asc')->get(); // return users who belongs to role id 1.

User::hasRoles([1, 2, 3]); // return users who have a set of roles.
```

Comment: I am using this package for roles and permission https://github.com/DynamicCodeNinja/RBAC  I have added methods to their trait as you suggested but I am then only getting returned query builder, and since I need all of the users, even the ones who have no roles, I don't think those methods would work for that kind of query

Comment: I 'm guessing you don't use `get()`? `User::doesntHaveAnyRoles()->get()` or `User::doesntHaveAnyRoles()->paginate()` ?

Comment: Then i I get 'Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select * from `users` where exists (select * from `roles` inner join `role_user` on `roles`.`id` = `role_user`.`role_id` where `role_user`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` and `id` in (1, 2)))'  when I use User::hasRoles([1, 2, 3])->get();

Comment: Then maybe there is issue with that package perhaps on defining the relationship, as currently I'm working on a project that uses the code above without getting that error.

Comment: User::doesntHaveAnyRoles(); seems to be the only method that works